# Add class after some callback with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, addclass

I have this problem with callbeck. So, when my list will be have more than 2 elements i want to add for the first one some class. I guess it works good but i have some ajax action for this and the list is loading after some click. Many times i'm cleaning content of common `<ul>` and then loads the "new". When i'm click fast to load next list all of elements recives class `active`. What is wrong with my code?

```
var sett_vertical_tabs_size = sett_vertical_tabs_breadcrumb.size();
sett_vertical_breadcrumb.delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    if( --sett_vertical_tabs_size > 2 ) return;
    sett_vertical_tabs_breadcrumb.find('li').first().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Maybe disable the click handler until the previous callback completes.

Comment: i did it, maybe for to short time...

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify at time. Disable it before the AJAX call, enable it in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a good place for $.Deferred

```
function getList(){
   return $.ajax({
           // your ajax here
    });
}

function showList(){
    return $.Deferred(function( mydef ){
        $('#listy').fadeIn( 1000, mydef.resolve );
    }).promise();
}

$.when( getList(), showList() )
    .then(function( myAjaxResult ){
       alert('fadeIn and AJAX request are both done');
      // 'myAjaxResult' is the server's response
      // put your class add logic here
});
```

Comment: note, if you STILL want the delay(1000) between, put in in the showList function as you had it prior.